# TAR doesn't work properly with the crontab

Tags: bash, backup, mysql, freebsd, tar

First of all, I'm saying that it doesn't work properly with the crontab because when I run the script manually it works fine.

The problem is that when I run the backup script with the cronjob and... it's coming to tar up the mysql dump, the tar archive has only `16` bytes size (and its empty, so it looks like there were no files to pack into the archive), the strange thing about that is that when I run the script manually, it runs almost 5~ minutes, and the tar package size is `~1.8GB`.

Here is my bash code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# Configuration
BACKUPD="/backup/mysql"
MySQLuser='root'
MySQLpass='xxxx'
# End configuration
ROK=`date +%Y`
MIESIAC=`date +%m`
DZIEN=`date +%d`
GIM=`date +%H-%M`

if [ -d $BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN ]
then
echo
else
mkdir -p $BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN
fi

for db in $(echo "SHOW DATABASES;" | mysql --user=$MySQLuser --password=$MySQLpass | grep -v -e "Database" -e "information_schema")
do
    mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --ignore-table=log.log --user="$MySQLuser" --password="$MySQLpass" $db >$BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN/$db.sql
done

cd $BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN && tar jcPf $BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN/mysql-$GIM.tar.bz2 *.sql && rm -rf *.sql
```

Where is the problem? Did anyone experienced a problem like this before?

Regards.

Comment: in general it's best to include the path to any commands that are not internal.  On my system tar would be /bin/tar

Comment: @gview I got your point, but I think the problem isnt the tar itself, but the mysqldump, which doesn't dump anything , then tar doesn't have a file to pack , so its empty.

Comment: Hey, your script is working fine for me. Can you paste your `crontab` entry and output of `which bash`

Comment: @Suku crontab: `*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/bash /home/utils/backup_ftp.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`, which bash: 
 `# which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
`. Regards.

Comment: crontab also seems perfect. Can you try with full path name for `mysqldump` and `mysql` inside the script.

Comment: @Suku You tha beast! :-) Thats was it - I had to specify a full path for `mysqldump` and `mysql`. Everything is working like a charm now, so feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as valid with the pleasure :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with full path name for `mysqldump` and `mysql` inside your script.

So:

> if `which mysql` is equal to `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`
>
> and
>
> if `which mysqldump` is equal to `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump`

Modify your script to:

```
for db in $(echo "SHOW DATABASES;" | /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --user=$MySQLuser --password=$MySQLpass | grep -v -e "Database" -e "information_schema")
do
    /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --ignore-table=log.log --user="$MySQLuser" --password="$MySQLpass" $db >$BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN/$db.sql
done
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the last line is your problem.  The shell glob (`*.sql`) in:

```
cd $BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN && tar jcPf $BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN/mysql-$GIM.tar.bz2 *.sql && rm -rf *.sql
```

is expanded in the current directory and not *after* the `cd` as you might expect.  Try the following instead, it is safer.

```
old_dir=`pwd`
cd "$BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN"
tar jcPf mysql-$GIM.tar.bz2 *.sql
rm -fr *.sql
cd "$old_dir"
```

There still might not be any `.sql` files to tar ball.  I don't have `mysql` installed but I suspect that the `for` loop is messed up as well.  Try something like the following instead:

```
mysqlshow | \
xargs mysqldump --databases | \
bzip2 > $BACKUPD/$ROK/$MIESIAC/$DZIEN/mysql-$GIM.bz2
```

You will probably beed to insert other arguments for the `mysqlshow` and `mysqldump` commands.  Of course this won't create a tarball but it will give you a compressed backup.

Comment: Unfortunately its not that `:/`, output package is still empty. +1 for now!